# How much outage time is involved in resizing an AWS RDS Multi-AZ instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

We're implementing new SQL Server databases in AWS. Our cloud engineer recommended RDS, despite the known downsides (inability to restore a single database or copy out a single backup, inability to resize the instance or reconfigure storage without downtime). Meanwhile, if we implement on EC2 we could get the benefit of zero-downtime upgrades.

In further reading, it seems like Multi-AZ may avoid downtime when resizing (see samples below) but the documentation is vague.

"Running a DB instance with high availability can enhance availability during planned system maintenance"
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.MultiAZ.html

"There is minimal downtime when you are scaling up on a Multi-AZ environment because the standby database gets upgraded first, then a failover will occur to the newly sized database."
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/scaling-your-amazon-rds-instance-vertically-and-horizontally/

**My question: does using Multi-AZ in RDS allow zero downtime when adding storage? If not, how much outage time would we experience when reconfiguring a Multi-AZ instance?**

Answer (score 3):

Multi-AZ doesn't do zero downtime, but we generally see less than a minute (with MySQL).

I would just create a new multi-AZ db from a snapshot, and test it to see.  It shouldn't cost more than a buck or two to find out.

Comment: Thanks! I just found this: https://serverfault.com/questions/613182/downtime-for-increasing-rds-storage

Is that accurate in your experience, that increasing storage size but not type involves just performance degradation, not an outage? (I realize there might be differences between MySQL Multi-AZ and SQL Server Multi-AZ.)

I'll ask our cloud engineer to test to make sure, definitely. Thanks again.

Comment: I think that question is from before AWS added the ability to extend a volume, so I'm not sure that it still applies.  Recreating a volume from a snapshot means you have a delay the first time each block is read, but extending an existing block incurs no such problem.

Comment: @Iucounu fwiw, I have increased storage capacity  on RDS for MySQL 5.6 numerous times with no apparent impact at all, on both magnetic and general purpose SSD systems, including non-multi-AZ.  It *seems* to be flawless/seamless.

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot , that's excellent. Our cloud engineer is going to run a test or two to confirm--I think we're all set.